# IKEA Off-canvas menu with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make with Bootstrap 4 a off-canvas menu like that of [ikea.com](https://ikea.com), but positioned on the right and always collapsed, both on mobile and on desktop.

I have searched the internet everywhere, but to no avail.
I really do not know what to do. Is there someone who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I see no *"off-canvas menu"* there. What means *"on the right and always collapsed"*?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan try to enter the site, for example, in Italian (https://www.ikea.com/it/it/). You can see on the top left an hamburger menu. When you click on it, an off-canvas menu opens. I want something similar with Bootstrap but aligned on the right and not on the left. The menu must be collapsed on all devices and not only on mobile.

Comment: Why Bootstrap? Can't you simply put some HTML, CSS and JS? (It can also be done without JS...)

Comment: Place a DIV using `position: fixed; z-index:1000;` set it's size and position `height: 100%; width: 300px; right: 0; top: 0;` than use `<label for="toggle_menu">` and a checkbox with ID `id="toggle_menu"`. Than inside CSS you can use animations and transition your menu to `transform: translateX(100%)` if the checkbox is `:checked`.

Comment: I'm building the website with Bootstrap. Anyway, either with or without Boostrap, can you please explain me how to do it? Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `hidden` checkbox. Than using CSS `:checked` and the General Sibling Combinator `~` target your `#menu` and *transform* `translateX` it with `transition`

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}
body {height:300vh; font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
main {max-width:80vw; margin:0 auto; padding:3em;}


/* MENU BUTTONS */

[for="menu_toggle"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
body [for="menu_toggle"] {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1001;
}
#menu [for="menu_toggle"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

/* MENU HIDDEN */

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1002;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #0bf;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3em;
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

/* MENU VISIBLE */

#menu_toggle:checked ~ #menu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<label for="menu_toggle" aria-label="Toggle Menu">&#x2630;</label>

<input id="menu_toggle" type="checkbox" hidden>
<div id="menu">
  <label for="menu_toggle" aria-label="Toggle Menu">&#x2715;</label>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <ul><li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum</li></ul>
</div>

<main>
  <h1>Hello, World</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I add an overlay to the page when the menu os open?

Comment: @AlessandroBuffelli not sure if you'll like it but the simplest is to add `box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);` to the checked ~ #menu styles.

Comment: That's great! I never thought of using shadow in this way.